# BUILDKITE_GIT_CLONE_FLAGS doesn't appear passed in call to git clone

Tags: environment-variables, buildkite

In my `pipeline.yaml` I define at the top level:

```
env:
  BUILDKITE_AGENT_DEBUG: "true"
  BUILDKITE_CLEAN_CHECKOUT: "true"
  BUILDKITE_GIT_CLONE_FLAGS: "-q"
```

However when my build runs I still see the default `-v` passed and not my provided clone flags.

```
[90m# Host "github.com" already in list of known hosts at "/var/lib/buildkite-agent/.ssh/known_hosts"[0m
[90m$[0m git clone -v -- git@github.com:org/myrepo.git .
Cloning into '.'...
```

In the UI under the Environment tab I see `BUILDKITE_GIT_CLONE_FLAGS="-q"` but it doesn't appear in the logs.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://buildkite.com/docs/pipelines/environment-variables#BUILDKITE_GIT_CLONE_FLAGS, this is an agent configuration option. So, one way to set it is in the agent's configuration file, which needs to happen before the agents start up.

It's most likely that setting it in a pipeline.yaml will be ignored, especially if the pipeline.yaml is in the git repository that the pipeline is for.